# DropZone works out of desired div React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a `dropZone` div where I can drop a file and it takes the file and gives a preview. The user can also click in the div and upload a file to do the same thing.

I am having an issue where when I use the `addQuestion` button in my app and drag and drop a file (image) it updates all of the `dropZone` divs visible with that image.

I am not sure how to make it so that the user can hover over the desired `dropZone` to update that specific one. Here is my `DropZone` component code:

```
class DropZone extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      file: "",
      fileId: uuid(),
      className: "dropZone"
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this._onDragEnter = this._onDragEnter.bind(this);
    this._onDragLeave = this._onDragLeave.bind(this);
    this._onDragOver = this._onDragOver.bind(this);
    this._onDrop = this._onDrop.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(file = "") {
    this.setState({
      file: URL.createObjectURL(file)
    });
    //document.getElementsByClassName("dropZone").style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + this.state.file + ')';
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener("mouseup", this._onDragLeave);
    window.addEventListener("dragenter", this._onDragEnter);
    window.addEventListener("dragover", this._onDragOver);
    document
      .getElementById("dragbox")
      .addEventListener("dragleave", this._onDragLeave);
    window.addEventListener("drop", this._onDrop);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener("mouseup", this._onDragLeave);
    window.removeEventListener("dragenter", this._onDragEnter);
    window.addEventListener("dragover", this._onDragOver);
    document
      .getElementById("dragbox")
      .removeEventListener("dragleave", this._onDragLeave);
    window.removeEventListener("drop", this._onDrop);
  }

  _onDragEnter(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
  }

  _onDragOver(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    return false;
  }

  _onDragLeave(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
  }

  _onDrop(e, event) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.handleChange(e.dataTransfer.files[0]);
    let files = e.dataTransfer.files;
    console.log("Files dropped: ", files);
    // Upload files
    console.log(this.state.file);
    return false;
  }

  render() {
    const uniqueId = this.state.fileId;
    return (
      <div>
        <input
          type="file"
          id={uniqueId}
          name={uniqueId}
          class="inputFile"
          onChange={e => this.handleChange(e.target.files[0])}
        />
        <label htmlFor={uniqueId} value={this.state.file}>
          {this.props.children}
          <div className="dropZone" id="dragbox" onChange={this.handleChange}>
            Drop or Choose File
            <img src={this.state.file} id="pic" name="file" accept="image/*" />
          </div>
        </label>
        <div />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

[And here is a CodeSandbox of my whole app.](https://codesandbox.io/s/1vy36n4wy4)

I am new to React and JS so explanations and/or hints in the right directions will be helpful as well. Thanks!

Comment: the problem I believe is the fact that you're attaching the ondrop event on window for every dropzone. That way, all dropzones are listening for all the events fired from all other dropzones, causing them to multiply

Comment: Ohhhhh I see. Ok I will try to fix this on my own. Thanks for the tip!